# What is the origin of the term 'blue ruin' for low-end gin?

Tags: etymology, expressions, slang

I've looked on google and so far I can only find definitions and usage examples. I'm particularly curious where the 'blue' comes from as 'ruin' makes intuitive sense

Comment: See https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/blue_ruin (pull down the list of quotations).  Nothing on where "blue" came from, though.

Comment: Related: [Origin of the phrase “mother's ruin”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/163917/origin-of-the-phrase-mothers-ruin)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to *Green's Dictionary of Slang*, "blue ribbon," at one point meant "the very best gin," and later came to mean *gin* in general.

> a blue ribbon worn as a badge of honour; thus referring to the quality of the best gin
>
> [early 19C] gin.

- [Green's Dictionary of Slang](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/vg4crva)

Green attributes this as a precursor to *blue ruin*, for the ruinous effect of particularly bad gin on a person's health.

The earliest uses I can find in either *OED* or [Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=J0YVAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA25&dq=%22blue%20ruin%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiKrtW9nZnVAhVBKiYKHVKjCZgQ6AEIKTAB#v=onepage&q=%22blue%20ruin%22&f=false) are instances of the term being defined as simply *gin* in slang dictionaries.

> *Blue ruin*: gin.

- *Lexicon balatronicum: a dictionary of buckish slang, university wit, and pick pocket eloquence* · 1st edition, **1811** (1 vol.).
  London

Comment: Thanks - that seems to make sense - the idea that bad gin was the 'best' at driving you to ruin - do you know anything about accents of the lower classes at the time? I'm curious if there was some kind rhyming slang going on with ribbon and ruin

Comment: @Edna I'm not sure, but an earlier variant of "ribbon" was "riband," which you could argue sounds like "ruined," to some extent.  You can hear the pronunciation here: http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/pronunciation/british/blue-riband

Comment: Purely based on my opinion researching another name (https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/163917/origin-of-the-phrase-mothers-ruin?rq=1), I would venture to guess that it was because of the popularity of the gin. A blue ribbon winner would have been a craze, which may have led to its popularity being its own downfall. As public pressure against gin grew, its popularity as a blue ribbon winner might have worked against it leading to loss of sales, etc, which then led to poorer quality, cheaper product, etc., etc. This is just me merely speculating though.

Comment: @Tucker I also wonder whether some brands of cheap gin claimed, falsely, that their cheap nasty stuff was "blue ribbon" quality. After all there was very little consumer protection legislation and even less consumer protection enforcement in the early 19C.

Comment: @BoldBen I wouldn't put it past them. I mean, business is still business.

Answer (score 0):

Could be related to the common name of a plant, "blue ruin" a highly invasive nettle also known as viper's bugloss, having a blue flower. Both kinds of "ruin" being somewhat uncontrollable.

Comment: Any evidence to directly relate the two?

Answer (score 0):

I read something that said , there was a low grade gin that for some reason would turn a person's skin blue if they were chronic alcoholic.  It seemed to affect motor skills much worse than other alcohol. You can find paintings of people in Victorian England that are deeply blue color,  emphasizing this

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Any alcohol will turn your skin blue if you drink enough of it. It is a sign of alcohol poisoning.